# Generating repositories with EF Reverse Engineer Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-power-tools

Is it possible to generate models' repository files with EF Power tools? How?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to generate them from the power tools but there is a NuGet package I created which will generate Repository and UnitOfWork classes for you:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepositoryGenerator/